# How do I evaluate this integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

What I did so far:

$\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \! \frac{1}{25sin^2x+144}  \, dx = \int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \! \frac{1}{\frac{25}{2}(1-e^{2xi}-e^{-2xi})+144}  \, dx=\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \! \frac{1}{25-25z^2-25z^{-2}+288}  \, \frac{dz}{iz}=\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \! \frac{z}{(-25z^4+313z^2-25)i}  \, dz$

With $z=e^{ix}$

Questions:

Is what I did correct? How to find poles? Do I have to change boundaries (from $0$ to $2\pi$) and if yes how?

Comment: Hi Ana, when we changed variables from $x$ to $z$, we should write the contour in terms of the new variables. Written in terms of the $z$ variable, the contour is the unit circle.

Comment: For the poles search for "biquadratic equation".

Answer (score 1):

**Poles**

Find the roots of the denominator:
$$
25 \sin^{2} z + 144 = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \sin z = \pm i \frac{12}{5} 
$$

Using
$$
 \sin z = \sin (x+ i y) = \cosh y  \sin x + i \cos x \sinh y 
$$
the poles inside the disk $|z|\le1$ are
$$
  \pm i\,\text{arcsinh }\frac{12}{5}+2\pi k, \quad \pi \pm  i \,\text{arcsinh }\frac{12}{5}+2\pi k
$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary integer.

The following plots display 
$$
 f(z) = \frac{1}{25 \sin^{2} z + 144}
$$

[image: function]

**Contour**

The integration contour, 
$$
 | z | = \pi
$$
is plotted in the complex plane with poles marked by $\color{red}{\times}$

[image: contour]

Resolve the contour into these eight components

[image: paths]

**Residues**

$$
 \text{Res }\left(f,  \pm i\, \text{arcsinh } \frac{12}{5}\right) = \mp \frac{i}{312}
$$

$$
\oint f(z)\, dz = 2\pi i \left(
-\frac{i}{312} - \frac{i}{312}
\right)
$$

**Conclusion**

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{25 \sin^{2} x + 144} = \frac{\pi}{78}
$$